# Fragment Error: Incompatible Types Required: android.support.v4.app.Fragment, Found: package_name.app_name.Fragment_name

Tags: java, android, fragment, required

I got an incompatible type error for the below code:

```
class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int i) {
    switch (i) {
        case 0:
            RequestsFragment requestFragment = new RequestsFragment();
            return requestFragment;
        case 1:
            ChatsFragment chatsFragment = new ChatsFragment();
            return chatsFragment;
        case 2:
            FriendsFragment friendsFragment = new FriendsFragment();
            return friendsFragment;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
@Override
public int getCount () {
    return 3;
}

public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return "Requests";
        case 1:
            return "Chats";
        case 2:
            return "Friends";
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
}
```

See the image below:

[image: click here to see the screenshot]

Can anyone please help me to get out from this error? And how to resolve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your class `RequestsFragment` extend the class `Fragment` from the package `android.support.v4.app`.

If you have already extended the `Fragment` class, check the import statements and make sure there is

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

and not

```
import android.app.Fragment;
```